# Avoiding DbSet objects count using ToList()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, count

Using C# Entity Framework v6.1.1, I was trying to make a Count operation on a `DbSet`:

```
//Items is a List<Item>
int count = db.MyObjects.Count(o => o.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ItemID == 1) != default(Item));
```

I did not use Contains, as there is a known EF issue on its use with Where Count etc.

Now, the above line throws an NullReferenceException, telling me that object reference is not set to an instance of object.

Changing it to:

```
//Items is a List<Item>
int count = db.MyObjects.ToList().Count(o => o.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ItemID == 1) != default(Item));
```

Works as expected.

Now, my assumption is that `DbSet` is working as a type of a proxy, loading lazily objects only when requested, something the `ToList()` forces it to.

I am concerned though about the performance of all this. Is there a better way of making the count of a `DbSet`? Am I really enforced to do the `ToList()` call everywhere?

I noticed that DbSet is **not** an [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset%28v=vs.113%29.aspx).

UPDATE: I forgot to mention that I have Lazy Loading disabled, and that I am invoking this code without having applied Eager Loading to the `Items` collection, which probably explains a lot.

Comment: Is Items a property of MyObjects that is lazily loaded? You could try to include Items when referencing db.MyObjects. e.g. `db.MyObjects.Include(o => o.Items).Count(...)`

Comment: How does EF translate `default(item)` as opposed to `null`, you could also try getting a count, this might also translate better into sql? Can you try `db.MyObjects.Count(Function(o) o.Items.Count(Function(i) i.ItemID = 1) > 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a materialization problem but to answer your title question, I think that

```
int count = db.MyObjects
    .Where(x => x.Items.Any(y => y.ItemID == 1))
    .Count();
```

should do

For investigation:

```
Folders.Where(x => x.Files.Any(y => y.IdPseudoCountry == 16)).Count()
Folders.Count(x => x.Files.Any(y => y.IdPseudoCountry == 16))
```

leads to:

```
SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[tableD] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[tableF] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[idDossier] = [Extent2].[idDossier]) AND (16 = [Extent2].[idPays])
    )
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

when

```
Folders.Count(x => x.Files.FirstOrDefault(y => y.IdPseudoCountry == 16) != default(File))
```

leads to:

```
SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[idDossier] AS [idDossier], 
        (SELECT TOP (1) 
            [Extent2].[idFichier] AS [idFichier]
            FROM [dbo].[tableF] AS [Extent2]
            WHERE ([Extent1].[idDossier] = [Extent2].[idDossier]) AND (16 = [Extent2].[idPays])) AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[tableD] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [Project2]
    WHERE [Project2].[C1] IS NOT NULL
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

But in my case I have no exception in none case.

Comment: why not `db.MyObjects.Count(x => x.Items.Any(y => y.ItemID == 1));`?

Comment: @NickDewitt hummm... because of course. I'm just more confortable with the first syntax (more close to SQL if possible). But yours is perfectly correct. The generated SQL is the same.

Comment: Testing it now.... could you give me some more details on materialization problem you mentioned?

Comment: @tschmit007 - each to their own I suppose, it will probably result in the same SQL being executed anyways tbh :)

Comment: @NickL. I'm afraid not, in part because if I mimic your syntax I can't raise the exception. But posting the generated SQL may help.

Comment: Have you also tried your original query with `== null` instead of `== default(Item)`?

Comment: @NickDewitt Yes, the problem is not there.
@tschmit007Your code works - in fact I tried it using `Count` as Nick suggested. I can not post sql code, sorry about that.

Comment: @Nick L. like you mention above, dbSet is not an IEnumerable, it's an IQueryable, you won't see the SQL in visual studio but you can check what gets submitted to the server using linqpad or something similar.

Comment: So what was actually generating the exception, was it the fact that the items table was not included in the query? @Nick L., did using `.Include(o => o.Items).` have any impact? It would be interesting to know as that would actually answer the question.

Comment: @NickDewitt It should not, all the logic is run server side (Linq to Entities). The include is usefull with the ToList() (Linq to Object), not without.

Comment: Lazy Loading is not enabled on the project, but the property list `Items` is virtual so it can be used with Lazy Loading too.

Comment: Does the `MyObject` constructor initialize `Items` property to `new List<Item>()` ?

Comment: It does, no doubt about that one.

Comment: @NickDewitt are you sure that on your code example, you are working with lazy loading disabled? I guess that my code would work if I had lazy loading enabled.

Comment: Because I am calling this code inside a deletion method, I am not using any `Include` for eager loading. I guess that by calling `Items.FirstOrDefault(....)` I am trying to access non-loaded data.
`ToList` probably does that loading, and `Any` is an SQL operation, practically, so this would explain why it went wrong in my case.

Comment: I have the same result (and SQL query) wiht `Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`.

Comment: It might be worth adding the code for the entity classes so we can actually get to the bottom of why the error is happening, are you using code or database first?

Comment: I am using code first, I am afraid though I can not post it as it is from a commercial project - the code above is modified.